# "Отчего заболел" или "от чего заболел"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: ***"отчего*** заболел" или **"от чего** заболел"?

Comment: Конкретизация - "от чего?" Т.е., предполагает установить точную причину. Широкое, с сожалением, размытая форма - "отчего [ж] ты заболел...." Можно без вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

ОТЧЕГО заболел - ОТЧЕГО - наречие в значении "почему", пишем слитно.

ОТ ЧЕГО заболел - от просроченного продукта; ОТ - предлог, ЧЕГО - вопросительное местоимение, пишем отдельно. Местоимение ЧЕГО можно заменить существительным.

Чаще используется первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что **в вопросах следует использовать слитное написание,** так как ОТЧЕГО обычно можно заменить ПОЧЕМУ, например:

Я сам у него буду!.. Чем он и **отчего** (=почему) заболел? На вид он такой могучий и крепкий!.. [А. Ф. Писемский. Масоны (1880)]

Местоимение ПОЧЕМУ предполагает **действие разных факторов**, пока неизвестных, а местоимение ОТЧЕГО - **какого-то одного**, что не совсем верно.

**В утвердительных предложениях** при указании на причину заболевания используется предлог ОТ (раздельное написание):

Я могу даже серьезно заболеть **от переживаний.** А я могу заболеть **от любопытства**. Боится заболеть **от беспокойства**. Мне грозит другая опасность: заболеть **от безделья.**

Он испугался прелести и силы ее лица, но из сожаления к своему сердцу, которое может напрасно заболеть **от любви**, отвернулся от этой служащей. [А. П. Платонов. Счастливая Москва (1936)]